# Append sqrt sysmbol to svg chart generated by D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to append a unit text to svg chart drew by d3.js.

```
  svg.append("text")
  .attr("y", margin.top-2)
  .attr("x", margin.left+2)
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text("Stress Intensity, MPa Sqrt(m)");
```

It looks like

[image]

How to insert a sqrt symbol and make it look like:

[image]

?

Thanks,

Comment: You could use √m ?

Comment: Using unicode: `"Stress Intensity, MPa \u221Am"`

Comment: @GerardoFurtado. Thanks, unicode works too.